# How to convert EnumSet<A> to Set<B>

Tags: kotlin, enums, set, enumset

I have an enum class thats something like this:

```
enum class SomeType(val id: String) {
    TYPE1("A"),
    TYPE2("B"),
    TYPE3("C"),
    TYPE4("D")
}
```

Now, I need to filter a list of `Something` which has a String that's stated in `SomeType` enum. So Basically I have something like this:

```
class Something(val id: String)
// where the value of id is one of the value of the SomeType's id
```

I have a list of Something like so:

```
val somethingList = arrayListOf<Something>(
    Something("A"),
    Something("B"),
    Something("A"),
    Something("C"),
    Something("D"),
    Something("A"),
    Something("D")
)
```

Now I need to filter that `somethingList` to by the given `EnumSet<SomeType>`.

So if I have a:

```
val someTypeSet = EnumSet.of(SomeType.Type3, SomeType.Type2)
```

the resulting filtered List should be,

```
val filteredList = arrayListOf<Something>(
    Something("B"),
    Something("C")
)
```

My idea is to convert the `someTypeSet` to a `Set<String>` and just do something like:

```
Set<String> setOfSomeTypeIds = convertToSet(someTypeSet)
val filteredList = somethingList.filter { something ->
    setOfSomeTypeIds.contains(something.id)
}
```

Can someone guide me how to convert an `EnumSet` to a `Set` of its value?

I also explained the whole process just in case there is a better solution to the problem above.

Anything will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `map` on any collection to transform it to a new collection with the desired values... i.e. `someTypeSet.map { it.id }` will already return you a list of string. If you really want to have a `Set` you can also use something like `mapTo`. Regarding the `filter` that might also be simplifiable using the `in`-keyword, e.g.: `somethingList.filter { it.id in setOfSomeTypeIds }`

Comment: Wow thanks! Can you post that as an answer so I could mark it. Also, is there a better Idea that doing what I did?

Comment: the only better idea that comes to my mind is to reuse the enum type `SomeType` on the class `Something` itself... that way you could just write something like: `somethingList.filter { it.type in someTypeSet }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) on any collection to transform it to a new collection with the desired values... i.e. `someTypeSet.map { it.id }` will already return you a list of string. If you really want to have a [`Set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-set/index.html) you can also use something like [`mapTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html). Regarding the [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) that might also be simplifiable using the [`in`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#in)-keyword, e.g.: `somethingList.filter { it.id in setOfSomeTypeIds }`.

So summarized:

```
val setOfSomeTypeIds = someTypeSet.map { it.id }

val filteredList = somethingList.filter { it.id in setOfSomeTypeIds }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function after you filter the relevant types.

```
val filteredSomethings:List<Something> = someTypeSet.filter { something ->
            setOfSomeTypeIds.contains(something.id) }.map { Something(it.id) }
```

It will return a List of `Something` with the relevant Ids.